# Can humanoids be reborn from a tree?

Tags: biology, creature-design, fantasy-races, biochemistry, humanoid

Details:

A culture of dryads has a strange death tradition. 
When a dryad dies there's usually a medic, or better say a "shaman" that rips a strange looking organ or gland off their head. The gland, shiny and the size of a hand, is then grafted into a tree.

After several centuries the tree is able to finally release a fully grown child using only the gland from the old dead dryad and minerals from the ground. The dryad will have most of their memories intact after being reborn.

I'm not asking if this is realistic, or plausible. 
I'm asking if the "gland" or any organ can force the tree to get the needed minerals off the ground and slowly build a humanoid child over the course of centuries.

Why this question? I wanted to make dryads immortal while avoiding over overpopulation and other problems related to immortality by allowing them to die and come back as the same entity but younger after some centuries.

Question: Can humanoids be born (reborn) from a tree?

Comment: Very interesting storyline. Good job!

Comment: reminds me of the piggies in Speaker for the Dead by Orson Scott Card

Comment: This reminds me of the Amar Kabal ("seedpeople") in *Beyonders* by Brandon Mull. They have a seed in the back of their head that detaches when they die. When planted, they grow back, retaining their memories but reverting to the physical state they had on their first death (which is traditionally performed at age 20).

Comment: I may be wrong, but can't we do things like graft orange tree branches to apples trees to have a single tree that produces both apples and oranges? If so, I see no reason why the same couldn't magically be applied to a dryad and a tree.

Comment: Hey, I want a Scarlett Johanson tree in my back yard. And if anyone dares create a Kardashian tree, I'm cutting it down.

Comment: @tj1000 - That's not Groot.

Comment: @tox123 reminds me too, however a bit different situation there because they were not entirely reborn, just still living i guess?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For various values of "dryad" this is entirely possible. Look into [agrobacterium tumefaciens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrobacterium_tumefaciens) for inspiration. Those bacteria alter the DNA of their host plant to create a tumorous growth. Look into [gall wasps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall_wasp) for an example of induced growth that has to do with growth vectors/plant hormones and possibly RNA/DNA viruses - this growth is much more structured than that effected by agrobacterium. So inducing a plant to grow some new organ, that is fed and protected by the plant, while inside a new dryad ripens - absolutely possible.

It would need some genetic vector (see the bacterium, but also many viruses), some chemical coaxing (which could easily be done by an entity as big as a hand) and the plant would be clay, waiting to be shaped.

Comment: Gall wasps always freaked me out. It’s like God decoded that all the existing wasps weren’t enough and tried to make them capable of genetic modification...

Comment: The fun thing on this site is that no matter how far-fetched some questions seem to be, often there is an answer among the lines of *"sure, something very similar already exists in real life"*

Comment: And then just to make it worse added on some wasps that parasitise the gall wasp larvae.

Comment: what about the memories ?

Comment: @GlorfSf if the hand-sized organ or gland is actually part of the brain - say, the part that stores the memories - and is simply used as the same part of the new dryad, it would seem quite workable :)

Comment: @GlorfSf : Actually i took Syndics way of thinking for granted - retain memories = retain brain  -  now that you mentioned it, i think it would be more wasteful and error-prone to mirror the complexities of neuronal memory to another medium, and then re-mirror it. So either the dryads have non-brain memories to begin with, or the transplanted organ contains parts of the brain, i'd say.

Comment: @JoeBloggs There's a third layer: _These parasitoids may, in turn, be preyed upon by other wasps, hyperparasitoids._

Answer (score 9):

**Sure...**

One would assume that the symbiotic relationship between dryad and tree evolved (or was magically/divinely created) that way.  Therefore, it's not just *any* tree this will work with, but a specific tree.  This is actually a good thing for your story because limited resources are always useful as crisis-creators during the story.

Given that the symbiotic relationship exists, the tree's genetics are wired to react to the presence of the gland.  One could say the gland injects a protein into the tree to trigger the genetic response.

At that point, the tree starts drawing nutrients as it always does, both from the ground and from sunlight (very appropriate for a dryad).  The gland metamorphosises into a cocoon, which in turn metamorphosises into a new dryad.  This is also useful to your story as the dryads likely have a hereditary disposition to defend/protect the cocoons.

In the due course of time, the cocoon unwraps to release a newborn dryad and then falls like any other leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Most parasitic or symbiotic lifeforms work this way: the host provides resources for the lifeforms to grow an reproduce. *Mistletoe* is a simple example of nutrient extraction of the host tree. On a more impressive scale, *Toxoplasma* make infected mice and rats behave in ways that make them easy prey for cats – the later being the hosts where *Toxoplasma* will reproduce itself.

Once nutrients are available, the process of transforming them into a complex lifeforms is nearly routine, as we all went through this process starting from a single cell. Centuries seems a long time, but the biology of Dryads and their hosting trees is speculative at best, so who knows?

A side question would be if the relations between dryad and tree is purely parasitic or symbiotic. Hosting growing dryads may benefit to the tree, as other dryads may take car of it and protect it from predators or diseases.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. Trees grow flowers and fruits, so if somehow the tree was altered where the instead of flowers and fruit, it grew embryos and had a sac to hold them until they matured.